# Cannot change color of Hr element via dash

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am using dash to create an application. In that application I use Hr to underline a text. I would like to change the color of the line, but I cannot do it. I have tried with both backgroundColor and color, neither works.

```
 html.Div([html.H5('Simulation time', className='card-title', style=FACTSNUMBERSYTLE),
                  html.H3("", style=FACTSHEADERSTYLE, id='key-current-time'),
                  html.Hr(style={'borderWidth': "0.3vh", "width": "25%", "color": "#FEC700"})],
                  style={"height": "33vh"})
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I needed to change the border-color property by passing in
'borderColor': ...